# Is Embarcadero C++ Builder a good choice as an IDE?

Tags: c++, c++builder

As we are (me and people I work with) more and more frustrated while working with C++ projects 250 000+ LOC in VS2010 sp1 (the slowness of this IDE is just unbelievable), in my company we were talking about migrating our code to some different IDE. We did some research, and a strong candidate seems to be Embarcadero C++ builder 2011 XE. Any thoughts on it? Is it any good? How does it compares to VS2010 ultimate?

Comment: 'Embarcadero' how many names had this poor Borland child had since the last time I used it...

Comment: I think you'd probably move to C++ Builder for the VCL rather than the IDE. Did you know it only produces 32 bit executables at the moment? 64 bit is slated for release in the next few months.

Comment: Have you considered to break up the project and evaluate Eclipse CDT?

Comment: @Michael from my experience Eclipse is as slow as VS, although from release to release VS is getting slower so maybe after next release it will really be viable option ;).

Comment: If slowness of new VS versions is a problem - have you considered evaluating older VS versions?

Comment: Either your computers are from the stone age, or you need to reorganize your code because you are including too many header files.  I'll take the "slowness" of VS2010 (which isn't that bad IMHO, and worth it in exchange for things like the smarter syntax highlighting) any day over the bugginess/obsolescence of C++ Builder!!!

Comment: Don't like it. Buggy interface, unintuitive shortcuts and behaviors, poor navigation of code. I hope we move to VS or Qt soon

Comment: I've used C++ Builder 2006, 2009, XE6 and RS10. I would do anything possible to avoid it as an IDE (even rewriting a large program in a different IDE). I would recommend using java with SWT and if that is not possible then I'd suggest using C#.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not actually an answer, but I'll just leave it here:

1. It costs money (yes, VS too, but you already own that, don't you?)
2. It will be not too easy to migrate a big enough project to new IDE (and compiler), not to say about the people you work with and their habits (I would just quit probably).
3. There's a new compiler too, with its brand bugs and caveats to learn about. And it's much less widely used than VC++. However, it's based on Clang, which should support standards better than VC++, and be easier to port existing C++ code to.
4. The difficulty of migrating hugely depends on the nature of your project (is it GUI based, how deeply does it rely on MS VC++ being the compiler?)

Comment: so basically, your advice would be, "not worth the bother"?

Comment: @user, Yeah. I would consider investigating the causes of VS being slow for your project. Maybe there's something you can do (reorganization maybe?). Or even hardware upgrade is sometimes an option (in case you have really slow computers).

Comment: brand new stuff (2011), multiple cores, plenty of ram. This.Does.Not.Help.

Comment: @user, just wondering: what exactly is slow: builds, navigation, basic UI experience? I used VS for many years and some gigs of RAM was the only thing it needed it seemed.

Comment: all of above. And this isn't only my opinion. Did you see that http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/filters/top ?

Comment: The VC++ builds are slow because it is an optimizing compiler.  C++ Builder builds might be "faster" but that's because the 32-bit compiler doesn't optimize well.  For one computationally-intensive  open source project we use, we compiled under VS2008 and C++ Builder XE2.  We found the code ran approximately 3 times faster under VS2008!  You can have slow builds and fast runtime performance, or fast builds and slow runtime performance.  Pick one!

Comment: Note that C++Builder has a Clang-based Win32 compiler, which gives pretty decent optimization. The comments above are based on the old "'classic" compiler, now outdated.

Answer (score 40):

I've been using C++ Builder since 1.0 and I hate it with a passion. You would think after all these years, simple little annoyances would be fixed by now but they are not. Here is a list of issues I have with C++ Builder IDE.

1. Your layout or personality never is maintained. You create one, save it and it only applies to certain things. For example the debugger window will not maintain its position nor will the message window. If you detach the project explorer it will sometimes dissappear. Most of the time reloading your personality doesn't fix this either. You are stuck dragging your windows back into place.
2. The debugger will sometimes work and sometimes not work. In a debug build if you set a break point and begin stepping through code, you can hover over a variable to inspect it. Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't work on the exact same variable. Crazy!
3. Eclipse looks for code mistakes like if you forget to put a semi-colon at the end of your statement, it puts a little ? mark in the margin. C++ Builder doesn't do anything like this. It gives you a cryptic compile time error message.
4. Recent versions of C++ Builder use a makefile similar to VS; it's an XML mess. Eclipse works with CMake and Makefiles. I've read in places that the CMake maintainers are looking for a C++Builder generator but last I checked this doesn't exist. I do embedded and cross compiling so sometimes my C++ Builder code is copied to my embedded development environment or shared with it and I wind up maintaining two build environments.
5. Not really an IDE but C++Builder does not take advantage of multiple CPUs to compile code. There is, however, a 3rd party tool you can spend more money on to get this. It's called TwineCompile (http://www.jomitech.com/twine.php). With Eclipse, they call out to whatever compiler you're using (gcc, etc...) and those compilers and make support -j option.
6. C++Builder comes with a limited version of AQTime which is a dynamic code profiler. Spend more and you get the more advanced version. Eclipse supports many dynamic and static code analysis (which also cost $$) but at least the plugins are there. We use Klockworx.
7. C++ Builder has no support, that I'm aware of, for external source control like GIT. Eclipse does. C++ Builder comes with subversion, I think, built-in. If it supports GIT, I could never get it to work. It tells me it doesn't understand the URL scheme when I give it a git path.
8. Certain template code I write causes the compiler to segfault and have to completely restart the IDE. This is nuts to me. You have a compiler that is 10+ years old and it's still segfaulting. I have a piece of C++ template code that when I take it to my work computer running exact same version of C++ Builder, it compiles OK, but on my home machine it segfaults. I'm absolutely sure there are no adverse factors at play like viruses, etc...
9. While compiling a large project that may take a long time, you are unable to browse code with the IDE. Sometimes you may see a compiler warning scroll by and you have to either wait for the compile job to complete to inspect the mentioned line or use an alternate means to open the file.
10. C++ Builder IDE has a concept of a Project Group with sub projects that are more/less self contained. The Project Group has no concept of a project group include/link path like the sub-projects have. Sub-projects have a base, debug, release paths where debug and release can inherit or block from the base but you don't have this at the project group level. The IDE has global settings which can be inherited but it's for everything you do in the IDE. So there is no way to modify for a given project group, just the include/linker paths for a set of sub-projects. I just think they could have done a better job with this.
11. C++ Builder's Build output is not color coded to, for example, show errors in red and warnings in some other color. Everything is black and white. VC and Eclipse color code and give option to change colors for various warnings and errors. The output tab in C++ Builder is same way. On big projects, it's very difficult to investigate compiler warnings with the other noise. In C++ Builder's IDE you can select level of warnings but this only affects output in the Output tab and you still get other stupid noise like letting me know its deleting linker state files "CleanLinkerStateFiles."

Unless you're doing Windows desktop GUI development, stay away from Embarcadero/C++ Builder. I started using C++ Builder version 1 back in the Borland days and have a few large projects that are heavily invested in the VCL so I'm stuck with it for those projects but all my new projects, I've been using Eclipse.

On a positive note about C++ Builder, the VCL is quite nice. It's not multi-threaded but it's nice for creating a desktop GUI app really quick. I think it's much faster to get a C++ based GUI app up in CBuilder than it is in VS. And there appears to be a ton of free and paid GUI components for CBuilder; again with a C++ focus. I know C# + VS has a wealth of GUI controls.

**UPDATE:**
I just ran into a problem today that is same as the one mentioned in this forum:
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=57631

> [ILINK32 Warning] Warning: Error detected (ILI4536)

Make up your mind. Is it a warning or a god dam error?

Scroll all the way to the end where you find individuals modifying ILINK32.EXE to get it working again. As of this morning, our builds stop working. We're dead in the water as we scramble to understand and find out what to do about this.

Is this the kind of compiler/IDE you want to depend on?  Again, this product has been around for more than a decade and it still has issues like this.  I find this completely unacceptable.  Crap product from a company that doesn't give a shit.

Comment: Just had to upvote what Eric said.  This compiler can't cope with leading open source libraries in some fields like Boost, VTK, OpenCV, TBB, and so on.  VTK used to have a bunch of Borland-specific workarounds but they ripped it out in the recent versions.  It's not that VTK used proprietary VC++ stuff, it's just that the 32-bit compiler sucks so badly even in the recent versions.

Comment: Pick a random 3rd-party open source cross-platform C++ library.  It probably won't compile in C++ Builder.  And it's highly doubtful the company/group behind that library support that compiler - most just support VC++ on Windows and maybe gcc (MinGW) or something.  Do you want to reinvent the wheel all the time, or use 3rd-party libraries?

Comment: They're perpetually behind the times.  Consider the VCL libraries never even widely supported Unicode until 2009, while Microsoft was doing this in the 90s.  Microsoft supported 64-bit C++ in 2005; Embarcadero took until a couple years ago to come out with their 64-bit compiler.  They still don't support useful C++11 features like lambdas in 32-bit C++ Builder.  They say a 32-bit clang compiler is on the roadmap.  When?  At the timelines they operate at, I doubt it will happen this decade and 32-bit Windows will be dead by then.

Comment: They have a new cross-platform emphasis now.  Sounds promising, right?  Consider these two facts: (1) some compilers are clang-based, some not - so your choice of architecture affects whether you can use stuff like C++11 or be beholden to an out-of-date buggy compiler, (2) their choice of string indexing speaks volumes.  One Windows/Mac OS X, their string class, UnicodeString, is 1-based.  On iOS/Android, it is 0-based.  Consistency is a real problem - cross-platform development is hard enough without your compiler/runtime just aggravating the situation for no reason.

Comment: I'll end with asking you to consider if you want to deal with crap like this in the vendor-supplied header file...  You really want to deal with strings that might be 1-based or might not be, depending on the platform?

`    WideChar operator [](const int idx) const _ALWAYS_INLINE
    {
#if defined(_DELPHI_STRING_ONE_BASED)
      ThrowIfOutOfRange(idx);   // Should Range-checking be optional to avoid overhead ??
      return Data[idx-1];
#else
      ThrowIfOutOfRange(idx+1);   // Should Range-checking be optional to avoid overhead ??
      return Data[idx];
#endif
    }`

Comment: @JamesJohnston someone still uses my software in Win2k so I would hesitate to make such a prediction

Comment: SVN support was added to the IDE in XE, GIT was added in XE7, and Mercurial was added in XE8. As for 1-based strings, that only affects Delphi-style strings. The VCL/FMX libraries are written in Delphi, and C++Builder has to maintain API compatibility with Delphi for them. But STL and c-style strings are always 0-based. You do not have to use Delphi-style strings in your code if you don't want to, they are only needed for VCL/FMX interactions.

Comment: I've been continuously using Borland/Embarcadero (C++ and Builder) since 1997. I liked these environments, but once I tried VS, I noticed how unfriendly and unprofessional they were. I have a few large projects and now I compile them both in VC++ and Embarcadero XE6. In this comparison, I hate C++ Builder. I submitted a serious bug report, it has been confirmed and upvoted by other users, and now it is over TWO YEARS of futile requests to their support asking for some action. First they said "you should have purchased extended support", then "we will investigate", and then stopped answering.

Comment: Adding to what James Johnston said. Embarcadero finally added support for C++11 for 32 bit projects in C++Builder 10 Berlin which was released last year. I converted my middle sized project (~200 k lines) to the new compiler. From one point of view it is outstanding for example warning and error messages are very clear and helps pinpoint the problem. Also the conformance to standard is much more better. Unfortunately this is more than compensated by its slowness. Instead of compiling projects in 90 seconds it took 16min 30seconds which is practically unusable for everyday work.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. As is usually practice of Embarcadero in last years the new compiler was half-backed with many bugs. What I didnt say was that I was able to compile my project only to 99% because of critical bug in some library header file. I worked with both VS (~ 4 years) and C++ Builder (more than 4 years) and I strongly recommend to stay with VS. The whole environment including compiler, system libraries are much more mature, better tested and less chaotic.

Comment: Just a note that some of the things in this answer (eg 1, layout not being maintained; 5, not doing parallel compilation; 9, compiling in the way) aren't true. And certainly for #1 were never true; it's hard to understand how someone who's used the product could write that. (When you change the layout, save it with the Save Layout button right next to the layout presets combo box. If you want it to be the new default overwrite the default. Or #9, turn on background compilation and keep using the IDE as it builds) As far as bugs - ok. But continually improving :)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Comment: ALL READERS! Note that this answer is from 2014. Most points expressed here are moot now.

Comment: ALL READERS!  Note, this answer is from 2014 and ALL points are still relevant.  Original poster here.  Paid, yes, paid for a new version of RAD Studio in 2019 to carry forward an existing VCL based  project we are working on and STILL has basic fundamental flaws & problems so much so I had to open a complaint with the BBB as recent as 2019...https://www.bbb.org/us/tx/austin/profile/software-testing/embarcadero-technologies-0825-1000130502

Comment: Their own community forum still has fundamental bugs with the product 
 https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/general-development/f/using-the-rad-studio-ide/68043/10-3-1-code-insight-does-not-show-methods-or-properties

Comment: @ServerOverflow It's now 2022 and most points expressed here are more relevant than ever.  Embarcadero's RADStudio IDE is pure crap.  We continue to use it for legacy software that's simply too expensive to rewrite but it's a garbage product from an awful company that breaks more than it fixes with every release.  I would caution **anyone** against using Embarcadero products for any new development unless you love spending boatloads of money on a low-quality product from a cynical company that takes any opportunity it can to hold you ransom for more.

Comment: @J... - I use Delphi and it works quite nice. The compilation time cannot be compared with any C++ compiler, and the speed of the exe file generated is exactly as fast as C++. Embarcadero is doing well.

Comment: @ServerOverflow Yes, the delphi compiler is fast - as in it produces an executable quickly.  No, it absolutely does NOT produce code that is as performant as a modern C++ compiler.  Not even close.  Among others, I maintain a two-decade old Delphi application that needs high performance computations and those bottlenecks are dealt with either using handwritten assembly or building those sections in C++ and calling them in Delphi through a DLL.  Emba is fine for small or throwaway applications, but it's a nightmare for enterprise applications that need to survive over many years.

Comment: @J... - It would be nice if you would point us to some Delphi vs C compilable code that shows you are right. The test already existent on Internet show the other way around. In some of them, Delphi is actually 5% faster. Again, this without daring to mention the compilation time for 1 million lines of code under C/Delphi.

Comment: @ServerOverflow I will say this - those benchmarks you're talking about are pure synthetics and they're doing simple things like tight loops of multiplies or adds, etc.  In that limit there isn't much the compiler needs to do.  Where C++ optimizations really show their power is in algorithms - of complex code - where whole-program optimization can find efficiencies with deep compile-time evaluation.  Delphi does very little of this, which is why the compiler is so fast.  There's no free lunch, and C++ doesn't take forever to compile simply because it's inefficient.

Answer (score 14):

There is nothing positive about Embarcadero XE, neither their aging IDE neither their aging compiler. Only use it if you're bound to it (legacy software) or if you want to do Delphi.

For C++, do yourself a favor and join 21st century : stick with something more powerful, versatile and modern such as VC++ or Qt.

Comment: The "aging compiler" is still based on old Borland technology, but it only applies to 32bit development. The 64bit compiler and mobile (iOS and Android) compilers are based on CLang instead, so they are modern, support C++11, etc. The 32bit compiler will eventually migrate to CLang as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  And when is that 32-bit compiler going to migrate to clang?  Will it happen before I die?  Are they just going to abandon it altogether?

They're too busy chasing mobile and other new stuff directed by marketing to fix what they already have.  Windows supported UCS-2/Unicode in the 90s.  Embarcadero didn't support Unicode until 2009 while VS was doing it for at least around a decade prior.  64-bit VC++ was widely available in 2005; it took Embarcadero several more years until a couple years ago... (what was it, XE2 or XE3 or something?)

I figure 32-bit clang won't in this decade

Comment: @JamesJohnston: The clang-based 32bit compiler is being worked on, it was not production-ready for the recent XE7 release, but it might be released in an Update Pack, if not XE8.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think Clang is arriving for XE8..

Comment: @JohnLewis: you are entitled to your opinion,since Embarcadero has not released XE8's feature matrix yet.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looks like 32-bit clang never came out in an update pack for XE7, nor is it in XE8.  Why am I not surprised?  From someone at Embarcadero sales: "I looked into your questions/inquiries with our Engineer, the 32-bit clang-based compiler is not yet released, but is expected to be available in the next release of C++Builder" ----- I'll believe it when I see it!!!  As I have said, perpetually behind the times...

Comment: @JamesJohnston: XE8 was all about iOS 64bit because of Apple's deadline, so the 32bit clang compiler was put on the backburner for that release. But it is on the [2015 roadmap](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/rad-studio-2015-roadmap) (slide #6): "*2015 New Platforms and Compilers - Windows 32 bit C++ compiler - LLVM based toolchain similar to the 64-bit Windows compiler language features, including C++11.*"

Comment: Just in case anyone missed it, Embarcadero finally released their new [32-bit Clang-based C++ compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32C) in RAD Studio 10 Seattle, alongside the older [32-bit Borland-based C++ compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/BCC32).  Users can toggle between the two compilers on a per-project basis, there is a new "**Use 'classic' Borland compiler**" setting in the [C++ Compiler Project Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler#Classic_Compiler) (the default is True).

Comment: Qt is punny compared with VCL.

Answer (score 8):

This question is really a matter of personal opinion.

I personally HATE Visual Studio with a passion, I avoid it like the plague.  My exposure to Eclipse has been limited to Java, but even then I've had a hard time working with it.

I have been using C++Builder for 15 years, since v3.0 all the way up to the latest XE6. Yes, it has quirks and limitations, but I still find it the easiest IDE for me to work with and be productive with, once you know how to work with (or around) them. Maybe my experience with it is hindering my ability to work with other IDEs, but so be it.  I still prefer C++Builder over any other.  But I only use it for Windows development (the VCL is very mature and robust), I don't do cross-platform development with it yet (FireMonkey still has a ways to go to evolve and mature).  And I do use plenty of open-source projects with it.  Yes, sometimes I have to tweak their projects and/or code to make them compile, but that it usually a one-time deal and then they work fine.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest Eclipse.

- As an IDE, it takes a little while to get used too, but it is well
  worth the effort.
- It's available for Mac OS, Linux and Windows.
- You need to have Java installed on your computer, but that's
  really a non - issue.
- It supports Cygwin, MinGW, and the MicrosoftVisual C++ toolchains. The build in CDT Builder     is pretty good too.
- You can use it to develop for languages other than C++ (Java , JavaScript, PHP ..)
- You can extend it's functionality by installing plugins
- IT'S FREE!

---

- Did I mention that it has a built in Web Browser ? Really useful for referring to online documentation, while coding.

Answer (score 5):

1.
We have a solution over 1M LOC and VS2010 handles it ok. We especially like /MP switch for compiling on all available CPU cores.

You did not specify your hardware. If you don't yet run on at least i7-2600 + fast SSD, I suggest trying hardware upgrade first.

2.
I used to use Borland tools a lot in the past. Delphi was rather stable; C++ Builder was much more buggy. Couple of years ago I helped to upgrade old Delphi projects to newer Delphi IDE with some service packs installed. And it had bugs even in the basic File IO APIs which have worked since Turbo Pascal. We had to downgrade to a previous version. I expect that quality of C++ Builder won't be much better than of VS2010.

3.
You did not specify what exactly is slow. You may want to convert some projects into components compiled separately. Also make sure you use PCH.

Also it worth investigating if you abuse C++ inclusion model by including a lot of unneeded header files in each and every unit. If, after preprocessing, Intellisense and compiler have to deal with huge amount of code, no IDE can help.

Comment: Xentrax so all those people who vote for improvement in performance of Very Slow .next are what?

Comment: +1 for the comment to check for unneeded header files.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate for C++, rather C# and C# web services development.  That being said, as a test between VS 2010 Ultimate and C++Builder XE, I have created a simple VS C++ Windows Forms application to click a button and show "Hello World" through an event handler.  Getting the button onto the VS Window Designer is okay, as long as you remember to access View | Toolbox.  If not, it will take some time to track down where the visual components are hanging out.

For reasons that do not make any language sense, the button click event handler has a signature that looks like:

```
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

}
```

and it goes to the header file as one would expect.  The `^` symbol makes little sense.  Does using it tie into the CLI/CLR better?  I expected a `*` to indicate a pointer.

After using the default Form1 (only header file created) and subsequently adding a new windows form, I finally obtained the respective cpp file.  Maybe the C++ Windows Form Wizard has a bug.  Who knows?  Anyhow, when adding the button click event by double clicking the button in the designer, the cpp does not obtain the method in either cpp form I tested.  Maybe this is normal, I do not know.  The end result of this is that after trying to use the MessageBox function within the cpp, it only caused compilation errors.  I am sure there is yet another header file that has to be in the include path.  I spent no time tracking this down.  Trying to set a label component text property caused compilation errors too.  About 20 minutes later, I went to C++Builder XE3 in frustration.

In C++Builder, I have tested VCL Forms, FireMonkey Desktop, and FireMonkey Metropolis application creation from the project wizard.  Sure enough, I have three different applications saying, "Hello World," in about three minutes total, all calling C++Builder's built in global shortcut function called `ShowMessage("insert message here")`.  The timing could have been slightly different as I did not time it with a stop watch.  It took longer to save files with meaningful names than the code itself: one line of typing in the respective click event body in each cpp (not the header).

The other main daily use gotcha with VS, for those of us who love the Brief key map, is that VS is highly challenging to configure into Brief.  When doing heavy development in C#, I use C++Builder's editor in Brief mode, saving files as often as I want.  VS does correctly detect file updates as you click back to the VS IDE.

On the slowness mentioned by the OP above, I suggest also looking very closely at the hardware platform relative to running Visual Studio.  I have noticed that if the .Net framework is out of date, VS will be slow within the IDE.  It does not seem to matter which language the project is in either.  I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Parallels with Windows XP Pro, with 2 virtual cores.  Generally, VS responds normally within the IDE.  While using it, I am NOT thinking, "VS is soooo slow."

Regarding migrating a quarter million lines to C++Builder from VS, I am not sure whether VS event handlers will convert by some wizard or other migration tool.  The `^` symbol, if consistently used in all event handlers, may not be a big deal for a regular expression conversion that is custom written.  If the project is very thin on the user interface layer and heavy in business rules and data, converting to C++Builder should be relatively easy.  I would expect some new coding for the new user interface click events passing the user interaction into the other layers.  For prototyping, using data aware components are likely your best bet.  In normal application running, expect to have the business rules layer use the STL and built in C++Builder data structures (even the `AnsiString c_str()` method) to interact with non data aware components.  The performance and user experience will likely improve.

**Start Edit**

A big knock on C++Builder XE3 (note this is two releases behind the current one of five) is that the 64-bit Windows support is only for console applications.  The knock is more from not being frequently broadcast on how to use the *Add Platform* sub-menu that appears when right clicking the mouse over the *Target Platforms* choice in the Project tree view.  This quick method to add more platforms to a project after it may first be targeting 32-bit Windows is virtually painless.  A new sub-dialog appears after clicking the sole sub-menu choice and a drop down box appears to select the new operating system and respective 32-bit or 64-bit versions.  In my opinion, Embarcadero is not demonstrating often enough how simple it is to add other target platforms.  So, to ease all developer's pain if this is not known in advance, I have found three web pages on the Embarcadero site.  The first one has pretty pictures of creating a FireMonkey desktop application.  Step 5 has the screen capture of the *Target Platforms* | *Add Platform* sub-menu choice for adding the *Mac OS X* platform.  It is here titled ***Creating Your First FireMonkey Application for Desktop Platforms (C++)***: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Creating_Your_First_FireMonkey_Application_for_Desktop_Platforms_%28C%2B%2B%29

The more terse and no picture procedure is here titled ***Steps in Creating Cross-Platform Applications***:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Steps_in_Creating_Cross-Platform_Applications

The Windows centric procedure and a small screen capture is here titled ***64-bit Cross-Platform Application Development for Windows***:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/64-bit_Cross-Platform_Application_Development_for_Windows

I have found on an Embarcadero forum post that an upgrade to the Update 1 XE3 release from the original XE3 release has a Target Platform selection issue.  There can be an internal path setting or two that is incorrect, and possibly having to change an original XE3 project file (.cbproj) to enable Win64.  Apparently the original release project file has this set to false.

XE5 (note version five as of December 2013) is supposed to have 64-bit Windows support for both console and forms applications (e.g. VCL, FireMonkey Desktop, FireMonkey Metropolis), OS X, iOS (Android coming sometime soon).  For the complete list, review the C++Builder feature matrix pdf for all of the XE5 details:

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/cbuilder-feature-matrix.pdf

Since the XE3 Update 1 has been shown to resolve Target Platform selection issues, when compared to the original XE3, there should not be any weird behaviors.  I have also come across an Embarcadero post that states from a TeamB member that for mobile applications, the Target Platform choices are filtered such that mixing a desktop platform project with a mobile one is not allowed.  So, if one wanted to try creating a desktop application and then with a mouse click force it into an iPhone, some other development tool will have to be used.  C++Builder and/or Delphi will not attempt to squeeze desktop components onto a mobile device.  You have to start with a mobile application project.  Here is the forum link:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96371

(**End Edit**)

If curious about my overall background, I have used C++Builder since version one, Visual Studio .NET (C# 1.0) and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  It seems like Visual Studio concentrates on C# more than any other language.  There are eighteen C# projects and fifteen C++ projects when selecting File | New Project.  To reach the Visual Studio C++ project area, make sure to reach it by opening the "Other Languages" sub-tree.

In recent Internet posts between Visual Studio latest and greatest and C++Builder latest and greatest, purchase prices vary in the thousands of dollars.  Even if never ever having an installation to upgrade either tool, C++Builder remains a bargain compared to Visual Studio.  Please conduct thorough research before spending your hard earned cash.  Hopefully both tools have 30-day trial installations to compare side by side, as your mileage may vary.

Comment: "The ^ symbol makes little sense. Does using it tie into the CLI/CLR better? I expected a * to indicate a pointer."  You're using C++/CLI; ^ means a managed tracking reference, which is not a pointer and is tracked by the managed garbage collector.  You can't do pointer arithmetic on a tracking reference.  Read the C++/CLI docs!!!

Comment: And, read my other comments about the general problems /w C++ Builder...  If you want to reuse other open source libraries, you're probably out of luck because the compiler is at least a decade behind the times.

Comment: "*the 64-bit Windows support is only for console applications*" - no, it is not, and AFAIK never has been.  The 64bit Windows platform works just fine for GUI apps as well.

Comment: For anyone looking for a summary about the `^` and `%` symbols, review this: [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).  It addresses all a noob needs to understand the difference between the C++/CLI garbage collector notation versus the C++ standard.

Comment: "To reach the Visual Studio C++ project area, make sure to reach it by opening the "Other Languages" sub-tree" - I remember this from older versions, but fortunately, this does not appear to be the case in VS 2015 and onwards.

Comment: In 2015 and likely 2013, if C++ is not enabled at installation, then the Visual C++ selection does not appear under Templates.  Regardless of that, a C++/CLI Windows Form project template is not present either.  You have to make one and then use the Export Template feature.  After that you have to review the contents of the exported template.zip.  It is highly likely files are missing.  This unresolved problem occurs in all 2015 updates.  Besides adding the missing files to the zip, review the MyTemplate.vstemplate TemplateContent section closely.  The newly added file names go there too.