# CUDA with C++ Builder

Tags: c++, cuda, c++builder

How can I use CUDA with C++ builder? Do I have to use a wrapper to do a basic CUDA computation? I searched and there is no info how to set the CUDA SDK for C++ builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NVIDIA's API is C-compatible, and C++ builder compiles to native, they also [happen to support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Calling_Convention_Options_%28BCC32%29) conventional calling conventions for C.

CUDA has a kernel compiler that allows you to mix C/C++ code with CUDA code in the same file... but I think they sort of embed a gcc version in the toolkit. I had a project where I was mixing code produced by another gcc version, and the easiest thing was to isolate CUDA coda in a library that I compiled with their nvcc, and then linked with the code produced by my gcc version. In my case, I had it easy: the C++ compilers had in common calling and name-mangling convention.

So, you basically have three choices:

1. Use CUDA's nvcc and gcc to generate C libraries that you can link with from C++ builder.
2. Trick nvcc to generate C code and try to compile it with C++ builder. I didn't succeed on this however.
3. Ditch C++ builder, you can still get nice multi-platform graphical user-interfaces using QT-creator with gcc/visual-studio

Comment: So can you explain in detail where did you fail when you tried compiling it? Personally cannot ditch it. C++ is C++. Couldn't care less about multiplatform.

Comment: @t0xic Check nvcc manual, it has improved since then. Specially, check the -cuda option, it might be what you want. C++ is C++, but despite what they say these days, C++ builder has built a reputation of not being C++ ;-). Just joking, but check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294688/embarcadero-c-builder-2010-compilation) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230518/is-embarcadero-c-builder-a-good-choice-as-an-ide)

Comment: I hope Embarcadero does something about this tho.. now not in 2030.

Comment: They have and are - try using a recent version.  XE4 was just released.  Those two linked questions are a bit inaccurate too, IMO - I'm happily using C++ Builder 2010 day to day right now.

Comment: @DavidM Glad to know. They have a hefty price tag though, and no column [here](http://www.boost.org/development/tests/trunk/developer/summary.html), which in turn is referred from [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/compilers.html)...I think that commercial C++ compiler implementers should take that page more seriously...